# Method to return either a string or redirect to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to a method to either pass back a string value or Redirect to another method. Is there a method class that can handle both passing back a string or redirecting to another method.

I am using MVC C#.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also, what have  you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by redirecting to another method?  Returning another view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a method with return type [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx)

If you want to return string just use [Content(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content.aspx) method:

```
return Content("string_to_pass");
```

If you want to redirect to another action, use [RedirectToAction(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) method:

```
return RedirectToAction("action_name");
```

Both `Content(string)` and `RedirectToAction(string)` are methods of MVC's [Controller class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460481.aspx).

As a summary you write your Controller like this:

```
public ActionResult FooDetail()
{
  if(heads_or_tails)
  {
     return Content("string_to_pass");
  }
  else
  {
     return RedirectToAction("action_name");
  }
}
```